# How to resize image using wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to resize image. Some times when we upload small image want to resize.

How can I do it?

Eg - When we upload `250px * 190px` image I want to resize `450px * 200px`

I used below code but it's not working:

```
add_image_size( 'img-fluid featured-purple-img', 475, 290, true ); // width, height, crop
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Image Size is just the first step.
To make it avaible in the Media Uploader use this code in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );


function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'img-fluid featured-purple-img' => __( 'New Custom Size Name' ),
    ) );
}
```

If you want to use the image size in a template, this will do the trick:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail( 'img-fluid featured-purple-img' ); 
}
```

Also I'm not quite sure how a whitespace in the image name affects functionality

Comment: add_image_size( 'fimage', 475, 290, true ); // width, height, crop

add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );


function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'img-fluid featured-purple-img' => __( 'fimage' ),
    ) );
}  I try to using this code but not working same results

Comment: you now mixed up your added image size name with the filter to add it to the media uploader. In the array_merge function change the 'img-fluid featured-purple-img' => __( 'fimage' )  to 'fimage' => __( 'fimage' )  
Also a hint: If you do this to images that were already uploaded you need to regenerate them using this plugin for example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ -> What this does is, that it takes in any newly added sizes and recreates all uploaded images. WordPress only creates sizes on upload or with the plugin